# How Can I make codemirror responsive

Tags: html, css, codemirror

I've looked in several places, but I'm not able to make my codemirror responsive, I've tried

```
.CodeMirror {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

but when someone doesn't give space / jump to another line the codemirror is wider than my container:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvMo1.png)

Here is my code:

```js
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
    lineNumbers: true
  });
```

```css
.CodeMirror {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.32.0/codemirror.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Detailed description of your Server * min. 300 chars(Markdown SUPPORTED)</label>
<textarea id="editor">

</textarea>
  </div>
```

even my div is changed in size,[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxZoJ.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1IoX.png)

Comment: Try `height: auto !important;`. I don't see the width overflowing in the snippet but if you are having this problem elsewhere maybe you are setting width to 100% inside of a container that has left or right padding?